How to apply Modified mann kendal test on multiple columns in R?
I want to apply Modified Mann Kendal test on multiple columns in one run using Rstudio, and save the results (i.e., p-value, tau, sen slope etc.) of each column in a separate dataframe / csv. The script, I am using works only at one column at one time. I have huge dataset. It will be time taking to run the code for each column separately.  The dummy data is given for your reference.



Year
A
B
C
D




2000
2
4
5
1


2001
3
2
1
5


2002
4
6
1
8


2003
7
2
9
3


2004
5
3
6
1


2005
7
3
9
3


2006
1
7
9
5


2007
1
6
3
9


2008
7
3
5
8


2009
1
6
4
3


2010
5
7
3
8



I am using following script:
library(modifiedmk)
setwd('D:/Newfolder/mktest')
df <- read.csv("mktest.csv")

result <- mmky(df$A)

write.csv(result, "result.csv")

Thank you in advance for any guidance and suggestion. If it is possible in any other programming language, then kindly recommend it. Thank you.

You should be able to use lapply to do this.
lapply(df, mmky)

The above code will apply the function "mmky" to all the columns in the data frame "df." To apply it to a subset of columns, you could do
lapply(df[c()], mmky)

Within c(), include all the columns indexes you want to apply the function "mmky" to, separated by commas. E.g., if you want to include columns 1,2,3, you would do
lapply(df[c(1,2,3)], mmky)

Make sure that you load the package beforehand using
library(modifiedmk)


df <- 
tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
  2000L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L,
  2001L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L,
  2002L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L,
  2003L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 3L,
  2004L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L,
  2005L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 3L,
  2006L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 5L,
  2007L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 9L,
  2008L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 8L,
  2009L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L,
  2010L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 8L
  )

library(modifiedmk)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  select(A:D) %>% 
  map_df(mmky,.id = "variable")


